# Sum from 1 to n in one line Python

Tags: python

Given number `n`, I need to find the sum of numbers from `1` to `n`.
Sample input and output:

```
100
5050
```

So I came up with `print(sum(range(int(input())+1)))` which solves the problem in one line but takes a long time since it's `O(n)`. Clearly, if we know the number `n` then the answer can be given in one line too: `print(n * (n+1) / 2)` but how to replace `n` with `input()` to still make program work?

Comment: .... is this for CodeGolf?

Comment: `sum(a for a,b in zip(itertools.count(int(input())),range(2)))/2` would work no?

Comment: @CoryKramer no this is a Russian training programming website.

Comment: You can squeeze lines in Python with semicolons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Act as if it's Javascript; create a function that takes a parameter `n`, then immediately call it with the result of `input()`:

```
(lambda n: n * (n + 1) / 2)(int(input()))
```

Comment: Close, but if you are in Python 3 you would have to cast that input(). Input in Python 3 would return a string. Other than that perfect answer. So like `(lambda i : i * (i+1) / 2 )(int(input()))` would work

Comment: You may need to wrap the whole code with a `print` otherwise it will just work from an interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3, one line, and shorter than the currently accepted answer:

```
n=int(input());print(n*(n+1)/2)
```

Comment: you forgot lambda

Comment: is two lines this code, you can put many ";" and tell that is one line, but it will never be one line ;)